# Save an object to database by using method from a different class

Tags: php, oop

I want to save an instance of Product class, for example, `$furniture1` to database by using the `save();` method that is inside of QueryBuilder.php. Is there a way to pass an object to it?

Is it possible or is there a better way to do it?

**QueryBuilder.php**

```
class QueryBuilder {

  /**
   * @var PDO $pdo
   */
  protected $pdo;

  /**
   * Create a new query instance
   *
   * @param PDO $pdo
   */
  public function __construct($pdo) {
    $this->pdo = $pdo;
  }

  /**
   * Save object to database
   */
  public function save($obj, $table) {
    // gets an associative array
    $variables = get_object_vars($obj);

    // arrays
    $columns = [];
    $placeholders = [];
    $bindings = [];

    // loop through variables and build arrays
    foreach ($variables as $column => $value) {
      $columns[] = $column;
      $placeholder = ':' . $column;
      $placeholders[] = $placeholder;
      $bindings[$placeholder] = $value;
    }

      // create strings
    $columnString = implode(',', $columns);
    $placeholderString = implode(',', $placeholders);

    // prepare query
    try {
      $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table . " (" . $columnString  . ") VALUES (" . $placeholderString  . ")";
      $query = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
      $query->execute($bindings);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
      return $e;
    }
  }

}
```

var_dump of the object attributes:

```
array (size=6)
  'material' => string 'wood' (length=4)
  'id' => null
  'type' => string 'Furniture' (length=9)
  'title' => string 'Desk' (length=4)
  'price' => float 199.99
  'size' => string '200x100x100 cm' (length=14)
```

**EDIT:**

`var_dump($variables);`,
`var_dump($columnString);`,
`var_dump($placeholderString);` returns:

```
QueryBuilder.php:81:
array (size=0)
  empty
QueryBuilder.php:82:string '' (length=0)
QueryBuilder.php:83:string '' (length=0)
```

Comment: Have you tried using this? do you have any errors?

Comment: It didn't do anything. No errors and nothing appeared in database.

Comment: Try removing the try/catch block and see if there is any exception

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'type' doesn't have a default value' in QueryBuilder.php on line 85`, line 85 = `$query->execute($bindings);`

Comment: By returning an exception you are torturing this great mechanism. Please leave it alone: do not return, do not catch. Just let it go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error you posted in comments, the problem is that in your database schema you have a field that is not being added to the sql query.

Most likely the object properties are protected, while  [get_object_vars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) returns only the visible properties.

Comment: `var_dump($variables);` returns empty array so passing an object as parameter is not working.

Comment: @Rudolph how does your object look like?

Comment: @Rudolph it cannot be empty because your query have to get the type field somewhere, to match the error you get.

Comment: @YourCommonSense see edit in OP. I did var_dump before preparing the query.

Comment: @Rudolph This edit obviously contradicts with the error you posted. Were your strings like that, you'd get a syntax error from your query.

Comment: @Rudolph are the fields public or private/protected? get_object_vars returns only the visible properties. Check the docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

Comment: Besides, "var_dump of the object" will never return an array, like it shown in the post. Looks like the OP have to sort their objects out first.

Comment: @Xymanek That was it. I had to change variables from protected to public... Thanks.

Comment: Don't be fooled that easy. Still the error he posted makes no sense in this regard. Looks like rather a typographic error of some sort.

Comment: @YourCommonSense The error he posted means "field 'type' is missing from insert" which is perfectly correct as it was not being read from the object

Comment: Mea culpa. Turns out an empty insert is allowed.